# a tag styles not working in ie6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have a page that displays two links side by side. This works on every browser except IE6. 
[Here's the link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQUTc/). Does anyone know why this happens, and how to fix it?

Result on IE6:
[image: Result on IE6]

Comment: I don't have IE6 to test this , but try adding float:left to the ok button class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because IE 7 and lower doesn't support `display:inline-block` on a default `block` element.

If you want an element with `display:inline-block` you can:

- Use a default `inline` element (for example `<span>`) and set `display:inline-block` to it
- Use a default `block` element (for example `<div>`) and set `display:inline` to it

You have `<div>` elements, so you need:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
.dialog-button, .horizontal-dialog-divider {
    display: inline;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/uQUTc/1/

It works on IE7, but maybe on IE6 this trick doesn't work (I don't have it so I can't test it).

But seriously, why are you programming for IE6? It's very old and it isn't a compliant browser.

**Edit:**

If you want to align the elements, you can use

```
.dialog-button,.horizontal-dialog-divider,.dialog-text{vertical-align:middle}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/uQUTc/3/

Comment: I just tried this after seeing duskwuff's solution. See my comment on his solution. It works for the most part, but the buttons are misaligned: [New page image](http://i.imgur.com/ILXE2.png)

Comment: @user886596 Fixed using `vertical-align:middle`

Answer (score 1):

Because IE6 doesn't support `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Adding display: inline to the Ok, divider, and Cancel seems to work for the most part, but the two buttons are not quite aligned on IE6. The cancel link is significantly lower than the button. Here's the updated page in IE6: [New page image.](http://i.imgur.com/ILXE2.png)

Comment: Well, yes -- `display: inline-block` is separate from `display: inline` for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better to use a list element, with float:left

```
<ul>
<li>Ok</li>
<li>Cancel</li>
</ul>

ul li {list-style:none; float:left; padding:10px}
```